# Angular 1.4 using ES6/ES7

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

I am starting a new project and want to use Angular 1.4 with ES6 classes for controllers, services, and directives. The best looking code I could find tended to use some sort of decorators, like @Component, but that seems to be an experimental feature of ES7 yet. What are some examples of Controllers, Services and Directives in ES6 for a real-world Angular 1.4 application?  I have my project set up to use Babel to transpile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not premature to build a project using ES6 classes with Angular 1.x. If you are starting a new project I would recommend using TypeScript or ES6 with Angular 1.4 or 1.3. You can then transpile this to ES5 which is the version of JavaScript supported in all of todays browsers.

TypeScript is ES6 with the addition of decorators and type annotation.

The `@Component` decorators examples you have seen have probably been for Angular 2. These are a feature of TypeScript 1.5. You can use decorators today. That said, you would likely need to write your own decorators that translate into what Angular 1.4 expects. You can probably live without decorators today.

With ES6 or TypeScript your `Controller` and `Service` classes should look like this:

```
export class LoginController {

    static $inject = ['dataApi'];
    constructor(private dataApi: DataApi) {}

    submit(login: LoginRequest) {
        this.dataApi.login(login);
    }  

}
loginModule.controller('LoginController', LoginController);
```

And a service:

```
export class DataApi {

    static $inject = ['$http'];
    constructor($http: ng.IHttpService) {}

    login(login: LoginRequest) {
        return this.$http.post('/api/login', login);
    }
}
loginModule.service('dataApi', DataApi);
```

In this example `LoginRequest` is a Data Transfer Object defined elsewhere.

**Update: Directives**

Directives are not classes, though you can create them as classes if you wish. I prefer to just create them as `factories` which they are.

```
var DIRECTIVE = 'mmTitle';

mmTitle.$inject = ['$window'];
function mmTitle($window: ng.IWindowService, $parse: ng.IParseService): ng.IDirective {

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: (scope, element, attrs) => {

            $window.document.title = $parse(attrs[DIRECTIVE])(scope);

            attrs.$observer(DIRECTIVE, value => $window.document.title = value);
        }
    }
}    
loginModule.directive(DIRECTIVE, mmTitle);
```

Comment: Make sure you use one of the more modern typescript compilers otherwise your typescript typings will be invalid. Older versions of typescript (like the one my company uses) do not support union types, which is something that angular and a lot of javascript libraries utilize heavily.

Comment: Thanks.  I will quit banging my head into the wall about decorators for now.  I can get the classes working with controllers and services, but haven't quite got it working with directives yet.  I'm missing something to bind the link function, but I will ask a separate question on that if I can't figure it out.

Comment: I updated the example to include a directive.

Comment: Thanks Martin!  I didn't see that update soon enough.  I came back to post what I was able to get working for directives.  The problem I struggled with was the link function.  The ctrl was there, but it was just my Controller, and didn't have things like $parsers populated.  I eventually realized I needed to require ngModel.

var MyDirective = angular.module('MyDirective', [])
class Controller {

Comment: Sorry about formatting.  I couldn't figure out how to get line breaks in this comment to work.
`var MyDirective = angular.module('MyDirective', []);  
class Controller {
  constructor() {  
    this.restrict = 'A' ; 
    this.scope = {ngModel: '='};  
    this.require = "ngModel";
    this.controller = Controller;
    this.controllerAs = "MyDirectiveCtrl"
  }
  link (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
    console.log(ctrl.$parsers);
  }
}
Controller.$inject=[];
MyDirective.directive("myDirective", ()=>new Controller());
export default MyDirective;`